# Нужен код на js для создания bb кода [img]

Tags: javascript, img

Кто шарит помогите. Нужно чтобы на странице текст `[img]линкнакартинку[/img]` менялся на `<img src='линкнакартинку' alt=''>`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = "[img]http://google.com/logo.png[/img]";
console.log(str.replace(/\[img\](\S+)\[\/img\]/, "<img src='$1'>"));
```